# Bootstrap grid inside tabs

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Trying to get this to work, but for some reason all of my formatting inside tabs gets screwed up.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<%= javascript_tag do %>
     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

    function drawSeriesChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($('.temp_information').data('temp'));

      var options = {
        title: 'name',
        bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}},
        explorer: { keepInBounds: true }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('series_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
<% end %>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6"><h1>Title</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6"><h3><%= link_to 'Go to Database', controller: 'articles' %></h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <%= form_tag articles_path, :enforce_utf8 => false, :method => 'get', :class => 'form-inline'  do %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <h5>Search Database:</h5>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'form-control input-sm' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>



  <nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-second-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-second" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Second</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-third-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-third" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Third</a>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">

    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <%= form_tag root_path, :enforce_utf8 => false, :method => 'get' do  %>
            <h5>Build a graph:</h5>
            <%= text_field_tag :search2, params[:search2], id: "keywords", data: { role: 'tagsinput'} %>
            <%= javascript_tag do %>
              TagsInput('#keywords', "<%= root_url %>keywords.json")
            <% end %>
            <%= submit_tag :Submit, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
          <% end %>
          <%= @keywordslst %>
          <br>

          <%= content_tag :div, class: "temp_information", data: {temp: @graph} do %><% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><div id="series_chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-second-tab">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><h4>Total texts<h4></div>
        <div class="col-12"><%= line_chart @articles.group_by_month(:date, last: 6).count.map { |x,y| { x => (@sume += y)}}.reduce({}, :merge), curve: false %></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><h5>Texts spread by subject (monthly slice)<h5></div>
        <div class="col-12"><%= column_chart @articles.group(:category).group_by_month(:date, last: 6).count, stacked: true %></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><h4>Total entries by category (total)</h4></div>
        <div class="col-12"><%= pie_chart @articles.group(:category).count, legend: "right" %></div>
      </div>

    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything that is inside tab "Second" gets shrunk down to the size of about `col-1` or `col-2`. Any ideas on how to fix this problem and get grid to work inside tabs? Also `bootstrap.min.js` is not included here because it's already in assets (and this is ruby on rails, but I doubt problem is related to rails).

Comment: Are you including bootstrap's javascript file?

Comment: Yes, it's already added and grid outside of tabs (including tabs) is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your second nav-item's href attribute is not matching your second tab-pane's id:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-second-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Second</a>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
```

Try this:

```
<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Second</a>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
```

And you are missing the third tab-pane.

Comment: Oh yep, forgot to fix that one. Third tab is omitted since it is no different from second. Post fix - grid still not functioning.

Comment: I tried your code [here](https://codepen.io/pinguinosod/pen/xjMqMW) and it doesn't shrink, it might be something after the code gets processed by ruby on rails. Try inspecting the code on the web browser to get clean html and share it.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Guess will try to dig deeper, gotta be smth with ruby then.